# StreamReader read file and StreamWriter write that result omitting first line?

Tags: c#, string, streamreader, streamwriter

Using the following code:

```
string lines = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"file.txt"))
{
    lines = sr.ReadLine();
}
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"file.txt"))
{
    writer.Write(lines); // Change this to skip the first line
}
```

How can I make it rewrite everything EXCEPT the first line?

Comment: Your code is completely wrong. `lines` is of type `string`... its not an array. Also, you're calling `ReadLine`... which, since it isn't plural.. reads _a single line_...

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do.You just reading one line, if you skip it,then you got nothing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
var lines =  File.ReadLines("file.txt").Skip(1).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt",lines);
```

It will write all the lines to your file except the first line and replace your file content.So basically it will remove the first line from your file.

Comment: I was using this method before but I kept getting the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'file.txt' because it is being used by another process.` which is why I switched to StreamReader/StreamWriter.

Comment: @Keavon okey then try to seperate two method

Answer (score 2):

```
var allLinesExceptFirstOne = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(1).ToList();
```